How to carry out a regression model (Fixed effects OLS regression model) with my multiply imputed data from mice r
I am carrying out Fixed effects regression using feols. I have some missing data so I am carrying out multiple imputation on missing variables.
I have carried out multiple imputation on multiple variables in my data set, and now I want to carry out regression on this data set. However an error occurs when I run the model using "with()"
Error in feols(.....,  :
You must provide the argument 'data' (currently it is missing)
The error is currently in feols but will persist in feglm.
Example below:
Here I make the example data
data <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:100,
  Var1 = rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 10),        
  Var2 = rnorm(100, mean = 30, sd = 5),        
  Var3 = sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE),  
  Var4 = sample(50:150, 100, replace = TRUE)     
   )

data$Var1[sample(1:100, 20)] <- NA  
data$Var2[sample(1:100, 10)] <- NA  
data$Var3[sample(1:100, 15)] <- NA  
data$Var4[sample(1:100, 5)] <- NA   


methods <- c("", "pmm", "pmm", "pmm", "")
pred_matrix <- make.predictorMatrix(data)
pred_matrix[, "ID"] <- 0  

imp <- mice(data, 
        m = 5,  
        method = methods, 
        predictorMatrix = pred_matrix, 
        seed = 500) 
models <- with(imp, feols(Var1 ~ Var2 + Var3 + Var4 | ID))


**Error in feols(Var1 ~ Var2 + Var3 + Var4 | ID) : 
  You must provide the argument 'data' (currently it is missing).**



I have tried identifying imp_1 as data however this does not work either. 

Any guidance would be great, still new to MICE. `


Update : still have not found a work around. Would be very grateful for some guidance
